# Aliasing SQL column field with date functions

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a SQL stored procedure query result like this (see below)

```
EmpID   FirstName Dept        JoinDate    Code1     Code2   Code3   Code4
 01     aaa     service       2017-02-11      0        2        3       5
 02     bbb     customerCare  2010-01-23      1        4        7       9
 03     ccc     Receptionist  2009-12-20      2        5        1       8
```

All these fields are taken from differnet tables by joining with a condition.(I have created a select stored procedure to execute this first weekday of every month)

My requirement is, I want to replace all the code fields to the start date. For example,

If I execute this stored procedure on March 1st 2017, The result should be look like this

```
EmpID   FirstName Dept       JoinDate 2016-12-01 2017-01-01 2017-02-01 2017-03-01                   
 01     aaa       service       2017-02-11  0       2       3       5
 02     bbb       customerCare  2010-01-23  1       4       7       9
 03     ccc       Receptionist  2009-12-20  2       5       1       8
```

example2:
If I execute this stored procedure on April 1st 2017, The result should be look like this

*

```
EmpID   FirstName Dept JoinDate      2017-01-01 2017-02-01 2017-03-01 2017-04-01
    01  aaa     service 2017-02-11          0       2         3         5
    02  bbb     customerCare    2010-01-23  1       4         7         9
    03  ccc     Receptionist    2009-12-20  2       5         1         8
```

*

That menas,

- code4 field alias name should be first day of current month
- code3 field alias name should be first day of current month-1
- code2 field alias name should be first day of current month-2
- code1 field alias name should be first day of current month-3

How can I do this? I am using SQL server 2014.
I could not find how to alias the field name with the date when we join multiple tables in sql server.
Please help me. Thank you for taking time to read my question and that you very much for your help.

Comment: You'll probably have to use dynamic SQL with a PIVOT to change the month rows to columns.

Comment: only dynamic query is needed

Comment: @DhruvJoshi you're right.  You could just use DATEADD to get the values.

Comment: Thak yu for the response.I know the dataadd functions but I dont know hoew to alias dataadd function with a column name.The code fields does not  contain any date as values.

Answer (score 2):

Put something like the following into your stored procedure.  This will get the current date, find the first of the month, and the previous 3 months.  Just sub in your own table. You'll have to put the rest of your query into the Dynamic SQL @query string as well as the non-code columns. Let me know if you need any help.

```
DECLARE @code4 date; SET @code4 = CAST(DATEADD(DAY,(DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()-1)) * -1, GETDATE()) AS date)
DECLARE @code3 date; SET @code3 = DATEADD(MM, -1, @code4)
DECLARE @code2 date; SET @code2 = DATEADD(MM, -2, @code4)
DECLARE @code1 date; SET @code1 = DATEADD(MM, -3, @code4)

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @selects NVARCHAR(MAX);
set @selects = 'code1 AS [' + CAST(@code1 as nvarchar) + '], code2 AS [' + CAST(@code2 as nvarchar) + '], code3 AS [' + CAST(@code3 as nvarchar) + '], code4 AS [' + CAST(@code4 as nvarchar) + ']'
set @query = 'SELECT ' + @selects + ' FROM [dbo].[myTable]'

EXEC(@query)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. I will try this and let you kow

Comment: It worked perfect ..Thank you very very much EMUEVIL

Comment: @Anj Great! glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

```
IF Object_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
Drop table #temp

;WITH cte(EmpID,FirstName, Dept,JoinDate,Code1, Code2,Code3,Code4)
AS
(
SELECT  01,  'aaa',  'service'       ,'2017-02-11',0,  2,  3, 5  union all
SELECT  02,  'bbb',  'customerCare' , '2010-01-23',1,  4,  7, 9  union all
SELECT  03,  'ccc',  'Receptionist' , '2009-12-20',2,  5,  1, 8
)
SELECT * INTO #temp FROM cte


DECLARE @Currentmonth DATE='2017-03-01',--Change date like 2017-04-01,2017-03-01
@AllDAtes VARCHAR(100),
@Lastmonth DATE,    
@LastBeforemonth DATE,
@LastBeforemonth2 DATE,
@query NVARCHAR(MAX),
@selects NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE @Lastmonths TABLE (Currentmonth DATE,Lastmonth DATE,LastBeforemonth DATE,LastBeforemonth2 DATE)
INSERT INTO @Lastmonths

SELECT @Currentmonth AS Currentmonth,
    DATEADD(month, -1, DATEADD(day, 1 - day(@Currentmonth), @Currentmonth))AS Lastmonth,
    DATEADD(month, -2, DATEADD(day, 1 - day(@Currentmonth), @Currentmonth))AS LastBeforemonth,
    DATEADD(month, -3, DATEADD(day, 1 - day(@Currentmonth), @Currentmonth))AS LastBeforemonth2

SET @Currentmonth=@Currentmonth
SELECT @Lastmonth= Lastmonth ,@LastBeforemonth= LastBeforemonth,@LastBeforemonth2=LastBeforemonth2 FROM @Lastmonths

SET @selects = 'code1 AS [' + CAST(@LastBeforemonth2 as nvarchar) + '], code2 AS [' + CAST(@LastBeforemonth as nvarchar) + '], code3 AS [' + CAST(@Lastmonth as nvarchar) + '], code4 AS [' + CAST(@Currentmonth as nvarchar) + ']'

SET @query = 'SELECT EmpID,FirstName, Dept,JoinDate , ' + @selects + ' FROM #temp'

EXEC (@query)
```

Comment: @Anji Try my query by change month number like 4,3 you will get column names dynamically As you expected

Comment: Thank you very much Srini .I will try this

Comment: Thank you very very much Srini...I took some code from you and emuevil..  Thanks alot ..It was the way I wanted